# How to make contents of a text file look encrypted and uneditable when opened through notepad which is inside the Local State folder

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

```
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, json);
        //ChangeExtensionToAdtAsync(file);
        string path = file.Path;
        File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

/*Tried setting the attributes of the file as hidden but still the file is visible*/

Comment: How about actually encrypting it? If your goal is just to make it *look* encrypted, actual encryption will solve that. You would need to store the encryption key inside your program, which is lousy security, but since you're only after the *look*, this should be good enough.

Comment: "Look encrypted"? Have you tried encrypting it? If you do (and do it through the shell and the file system) it won't "look encrypted" to you, but it will to everyone else. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Encrypting and decrypting is costlier. I need to write the contents of JSON into the file which is would use to send API requests. I just want to make the text unreadable by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the contents of the file in something other than ASCII or Unicode.  Base64 is commonly used in web sites and there are framework methods that convert your string to Base64 and vice versa.  Base64 is a char array, but  you can ToString() it.

```
char[] fileContents = Convert.ToBase64String(json);
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, fileContents.ToString());
```

and then something like this

```
var base64contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var readableText = Convert.FromBase64String(base64contents);
```

Comment: how to make the file uneditable by the user ??. And restrict the access for writing into the file using any kind of editing tools, e.g:- Notepad, Notepad++ etc

Comment: If a user doesn't understand the encoding they can't edit it in a meaningful sense.  Here is my username in Base64.  VGhlTWlrZUluTllD  Try to add a space to it. They can destroy it by opening it up in an editor and changing the contents, but then it probably won't decode properly.  If you want to physically stop a user from opening a file on their machine then I'm sorry, I didn't understand your intent, and it's not something commonly done or even possible really.